# Fixing over-payment for the last month in a mortgage calculator program

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve this problem from David Beazly's Practical Python where there happens to be an over-payment for the last mortgage payment according to the following code which needs to be fixed:

```
principal = 500000.0
rate = 0.05 
payment = 2684.11 
total_paid = 0.0 
month = 0

extra_payment_start_month = 61 
extra_payment_end_month = 108 extra_payment = 1000


while principal > 0: 
    month += 1 principal = principal * (1+rate/12) - payment 
    total_paid = total_paid + payment
    
    if month >= extra_payment_start_month and month <= extra_payment_end_month:
        principal = principal - extra_payment
        total_paid = total_paid + extra_payment

    print(month, round(total_paid,2), round(principal, 2))

print('Total paid', round(total_paid, 2)) print('Months', month)
```

This results in an overpayment:

```
...
308 874705.88 3478.83
309 877389.99 809.21
310 880074.1 -1871.53 
Total paid 880074.1 
Months 310
```

When I try to make the last payment based on the principal remaining into account using the following code:

```
principal = 500000.0
rate = 0.05 
payment = 2684.11 
total_paid = 0.0 
month = 0

extra_payment_start_month = 61 
extra_payment_end_month = 108 
extra_payment = 1000

while principal > 0: 
    month += 1 
    principal = principal * (1+rate/12) - payment 
    total_paid = total_paid + payment

# If remaining principal is less than the default payment amount:

    if principal < payment:
        payment = principal * (1+rate/12)
        total_paid = total_paid + payment

    if month >= extra_payment_start_month and month <= extra_payment_end_month:
        principal = principal - extra_payment
        total_paid = total_paid + extra_payment

    print(month, round(total_paid,2), round(principal, 2))

print('Total paid', round(total_paid, 2)) print('Months', month)
```

I get this:

```
...
308 874705.88 3478.83
309 878202.57 809.21 
310 879015.16 0.0 
Total paid 879015.16 
Months 310
```

I feel like I'm doing something wrong because the total payment for the month `309` is out of order from what it's supposed to be and mathematically the total payment at the end should be `878202.57`.

Could I please get pointers on how to fix this?

Comment: 878202.57, how do you get at that number? Also, for a [mcve], it might be helpful if you simplified this, in particular not a 300-month loan that you can't compute with pen&paper.

Comment: BTW: If `rate` is the annual rate on the loan, then the equivalent monthly rate is not `rate/12` but `rate**(1/12)`. That might be your issue already.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: Subtracting the over-paid amount from the total paid gives me that number. Alternatively when I add the calculate the interest for the principal balance for month# 309 and add that to the total paid until 309th month, gives me 878202.57.
Oh and you're right about the monthly rate for the last payment that I should've applied. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are updating the `total_paid` when you shouldn't, when the principal gets less than the payment.

So on iteration 309, you pay normally, then you check that the remaining principal is less than the stipulated payment, so you update the payment quantity. But then you also add that new payment to the `total_paid`, which is wrong because you haven't really paid that yet.

So just remove that extra `total_paid` update and things will make sense again.
Also, the comment on converting from annual to monthly rate is important, as you always compute the interest on the remaining principal, you have a compounding interest structure, that evolves geometrically (just think of what would happen if you didn't pay anything for a whole year, how much interest you need monthly to have 5% at the end of the year.

```
month 0 => principal
month 1 => principal*(1+monthly_rate)
month 2 => principal*(1+monthly_rate)*(1+monthly_rate)
...
month 12 => principal*(1+monthly_rate)^12 = principal*(1+anual_rate)

so (1+monthly_rate)^12 = 1+anual_rate
1+monthly_rate = (1+anual_rate)^(1/12)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I think I got the answer now.